# How to bind properties to another UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

ItemsControl is associated with a collection of objects. As a template, 2 other UserControl are used, which need to associate properties with the properties of the collection objects. I do this:

```
<local:DayControl Date="{Binding Date}"/>
<local:IntervalControl Intervals="{Binding Intervals}"/>
```

But it does not work! We have to do this:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="date" Text="{Binding Date}" Visibility="Hidden"/>
<ItemsControl x:Name="items" ItemsSource="{Binding Intervals}"/>
<local:DayControl Date="{Binding ElementName=date, Path=Text}"/>
<local:IntervalControl Intervals="{Binding ElementName=items, Path=ItemsSource}"/>
```

How to do it right?

Comment: Please translate your question to English.

Comment: or post to [ru.so]

Comment: @steve all is ready

Comment: @jjj all is ready

Comment: @СергейПолынцев, not enough context to determine the reason of this issue. wild guess: do you set DataContext in `DayControl`? (if yes, don't do it)

Comment: @ash No, I do not touch DataContext

Answer (score 0):

Check data types for Binding values and what your controls expect.

[If you want to databind ... properties that have incompatible types, you need a piece of code in between, that converts the value from source to target type and back.](https://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)

It seems you need a converter in your code-behind here and at the moment you employ implicit type conversion through TextBlock (to String) and through ItemsControl (to IEnumerable?).